# Paying for Airbnb bookings with another person's credit card

Tags: bookings, payment-cards, airbnb

I wish to book Airbnb accommodation for an overseas trip.  Unfortunately, the charge would put the credit card balance over the limit.  I can have another person pay with their card but I'm not sure this is a generally accepted practice.

I could not find anything on Airbnb's website about this.  I do know that booking for another person with my account is not allowed, but that is not the case here.  I'm booking my own stay, I just want to pay with someone else's card.

This seems to be a closely related but slightly different question: [Booking hotel with my credit card for a third person. Will that person have issues at check-in?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21279/booking-hotel-with-my-credit-card-for-the-third-person)

Edit:
I used Airbnb's Contact Us page to ask this same question.  Someone with a title of 'Airbnb expert' answered that it should be fine.  However, it is unclear to me whether this person is an Airbnb support employee or a specially selected Airbnb user.

Here's what it says on the support page where the answer was posted:

> This is a private conversation between you and verified Airbnb experts. These experts were selected by Airbnb and matched to your question to get you the help you need.

**Update: I booked the rental and made the trip with no issue.**

Comment: I have the same situation. I booked for my stay using my partner's cc. Until now it is "pending". The host doesn't even reply to my chat messages to her. I am thinking would it be about the cc. I asked my partner if he has received any email or text from his CC company and he said he hasn't. I asked airbnb and the expert told me to just wait within 24 hours starting from the time I made the request. The host is supposed to be a superhost so I was expecting for her to be responsive.

Comment: @FlorDonaire the issue probably isn't the card.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

arbnb charges the credit card as soon as the booking is accepted. If the payment goes through then airbnb has accepted it. If the payment has not been reversed in the day or two afterwards, you should have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 5):

**I have in the past (ca. 2 years ago) successfully booked and stayed at Airbnbs using another person's credit card, without the card holder staying with me. It is fine.**

I also agree with @Berwyn that once the booking has gone through you are fine. Some airlines do have the hassle of asking for the credit card used for the booking at check in and once I did encounter this at a hotel, but I yet have to stay at an Airbnb where the host even checks my ID, so you really don't have to worry about that either.

The card holder may however be interested in that you don't tick the "store credit card info" option. It is not possible to delete credit card info from your Airbnb profile if it's the only card registered and would show up for any future booking you make.

Comment: Good point about deleting the cardholder data from my account.